# How to make search result clickable as if clicking a button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a html page with a form and input fields. When a user enters text into the input field, at each key a database is searched for corresponding values. This is done through a Javascript call which then does an XMLHttpRequest to a PHP script. In the PHP I return a top 10 list of matches. This list is then shown on the html page.

What I now would like is to make each item in the list clickable and when clicked it should fill the form field with the value. I can make the results linkable by adding `<a href>`  around them, but the onClick doesn't seem to work for it.

Html/PHP page with form:

```
<form action="index.php?page=n0402" method="post" Name="AddPolish" >
    <div id="frmBrandInput">
        <label for="frmBrand">Brand name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="frmBrand" size="50" onkeyup="n0401CheckRecords(1);" onchange="n0401AddResults_Clear();" maxlength="100" id="frmBrand"   />
    </div>
    <div id="ListResults">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <div class="n0401AddResults" id="n0401AddResults_Status">
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit-value">ADD</button>
</form>
```

The javascript calls the PHP and changes the n0401AddResults_Status:

```
function n0401CheckRecords( jsCheck){
---- xmlhttp request code and return snipped out --- 
document.getElementById("n0401AddResults_Status").innerHTML = return_data;
}
```

The PHP page that checks the database:

```
While ($dbCheck_result = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<li class='CheckListItem' onClick='ClickMe();'><a href='".$dbCheck_result[1]."'>".$dbCheck_result[1] ."</a></li>";
}
```

What is the best way to structure that return string to make it clickable? Btw, I'm now using a list for it, but that is not a requirement to me.

Btw I'm NOT using JQuery.

Comment: If you click on the link it will follow the link and reload the page, so the `onclick` function will not be executed.

Comment: Unless you use a '#' link (i.e. http://www.google.com/#noreload)

Comment: What is `$dbCheck_result[1]`?

Comment: $dbCheck_result[1] is the database field. But I need to change that to be the value of a function I should call. For example: onClick('ClickMe($dbCheck_result[1]);').

Comment: So i need to change the <a href> to just # and then the onClick should work?

Comment: Worked !!! Changed this line:
`echo "<li class='CheckListItem' onClick='ClickMe(\"".$dbCheck_result[1]."\");'><a href='#'>".$dbCheck_result[1] ."</a></li>";`

Answer (score 2):

I should have used the # for `<a href>`. Solution was to use this line:

```
echo "<li class='CheckListItem' onClick='ClickMe(\"".$dbCheck_result[1]."\");'><a href='#'>".$dbCheck_result[1] ."</a></li>";
```